# mod_security RBL - apparent false positive

Tags: mod-security, rbl

I'm struggling with an RBL rule in mod_security under apache 2.2 that seems to be giving me a false positive. I see the following in the audit log (IP address redacted):

> Message: RBL lookup of 4.3.2.1.sbl-xbl.spamhaus.org succeeded at REMOTE_ADDR. [file "/etc/httpd/modsecurity.d/activated_rules/modsecurity_crs_42_comment_spam.conf"] [line "21"] [id "981138"] [msg "RBL Match for SPAM Source"] [severity "CRITICAL"] [tag "AUTOMATION/MALICIOUS"]

The part that is driving me nuts is that if I do an `nslookup` on the name specified in the log message I get a result that it does not exist. Which as I understand it means that this address is not on the list.  So why is mod_security getting a success?

I've also used the lookup service at spamhaus to confirm that the IP address is not black-listed.

What am I missing?  It feels like something is being cached but I can't figure out where.

A bit more background, initially the host was using a DNS server that was (helpfully) returning addresses even when lookup was failing.  I've switched the config to use the google servers (8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4) and now `host` and `nslookup` work as I expect.  I've rebooted the server so in theory there's no in memory cache.  I've also made sure the mod_security data files that would preserve the IP address are cleared.  I know that's working since the initial lookup for the address appears as above, and subsequent ones, after the initial false success show the address as a known SPAM address.

The rule in question:

```
SecRule REMOTE_ADDR "@rbl sbl-xbl.spamhaus.org" \
"phase:1,id:'981138',t:none,pass,nolog,auditlog,msg:'RBL Match for SPAM Source',\
tag:'AUTOMATION/MALICIOUS',severity:'2',setvar:'tx.msg=%{rule.msg}',\
setvar:tx.automation_score=+%{tx.warning_anomaly_score},\
setvar:tx.anomaly_score=+%{tx.warning_anomaly_score},\
setvar:tx.%{rule.id}-AUTOMATION/MALICIOUS-%{matched_var_name}=%{matched_var},\
setvar:ip.spammer=1,expirevar:ip.spammer=86400,setvar:ip.previous_rbl_check=1,\
expirevar:ip.previous_rbl_check=86400,skipAfter:END_RBL_CHECK"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm no longer seeing this problem and I suspect I know the cause.

1. The name server was configured to search for names within mydomain.com via "search" setting in /etc/resolv.conf
2. I had a wildcard DNS entry for *.mydomain.com returning an IP address

(1) remains true, but I've removed the wildcard DNS entry so now a search for example.com will no longer result in a match on example.com.mydomain.com